# Find and Replace specific text and random numbers with mySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL Workbench to edit data in columns. The data is in the form of

[random integer 1][constant string][Data I want to keep intact][random Integer 2]

I want to develop a query to remove the [Random integers] on the beginning and end as well as the [constant string].
I can remove the [constant string] using a script like:

```
update [table_name] set [column_name] = replace([column_name], '[constant string]','');
```

But then i am still left with:
[random integer 1][Data I want to keep intact][random Integer 2].

Can anyone help me write a script to use in mySQL Workbench that will work for the entire table? I have more than one by the way and some are very large, all with the same pattern problem.
Examples of this integer are: "16", "123", "225" and such. It is always 1-3 digits.

To reiterate, I want something that will strip [random integer 1],[constant string] and [random Integer 2]
from [random integer 1][constant string][Data I want to keep intact][random Integer 2]

An example of what this looks like before and after is:

```
rows
"85-STRING-Undo 250"
"140-STRING-js: E.undo(); 194" 

Desired result
"Undo"
"js: E.undo();"
```

This may be similar to another question, but I could not get any answer I needed from it.

Comment: Can you add some example data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this would be to build a regexp to match your pattern and use regexp replace to remove the unnecessary parts.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have regexp replace built in, however you could use a user defined function.

Fortunately, this has already been developed: https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp